# Converting User TimeZone date to UTC, writing converter

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, timezone

I have an `Action` class as:

```
public class Action implements Serializable {
    private Integer actionID;
    private Integer actionStatus;
    private User    user;
    private Date    actionDueDate;
 }
```

I am using hibernate to store the `Action`. The user selects the `actionDueDate` in his own timezone.

1. I want the `Action's` `actionDueDate` to be converted to UTC, after converting User timezone to UTC.
   Please suggest me how can this be done.
   I am happy to write my own conversion, but wondering if Hibernate can handle this automatically, or if there is some other better way.
   My database is MySQL.
2. Is there a way we can specify the order in which the object properties get initialized
   in Java/Hibernate? Because if I am writing my own converter, I would need the `User` property to get initialized before `actionDueDate`.

Comment: Is actionDueDate a java.util.Date?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date doesn't carry any time zone information; it's essentially a thin wrapper around the long returned by getTime(). Change actionDueDate to a Long and persist that instead.

Or use Joda-Time and change actionDueDate to a org.joda.time.DateTime which *does* carry a time zone, and use [joda-contrib](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/) for integration with Hibernate 3.x or the [usertype project](http://jadira.sourceforge.net) for integration with Hibernate 4.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have implemented without converting explicitly to long. This takes care of the Daylight saving as well.
Will your suggestion, to use getTime() take care for Daylight saving?
What do you think of the answer I have posted.

Comment: +1 for store your date as a timestamp.  This eliminates the confusion of time zones.

Comment: The requirements is to have timezones implemented and look for daylight saving as well. Date can definitely be stored as milliseconds but for using it with different timezones you have to add and subtract the milliseconds, and if we use this way we have to add another layer of complexity for Daylight saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Internationalization Concept in java where we can get the localtime etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormatUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatlocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormatlocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
        Date localDate=new Date();
        Date atUTC = dateFormatlocal.parse(dateFormatUTC.format(localDate));

        System.out.println("@Local: "+localDate.toString());
    System.out.println("@UTC: "+atUTC.toString());
```

This takes care of the Daylight saving as well.
What do you think.

Output:

```
@Local: Thu Jun 27 08:45:32 EST 2013
@UTC: Thu Jun 27 15:45:32 EST 2013
```

Comment: Jahroy, As mentioned in the question, I am looking to convert from one timezone to another, and the code that I have posted is doing that. I know date is a date is a date, but date at one place at that moment is not the same at the same moment at different place, thats why we have timezones, and I am looking for converting from one timezone to another. I believe your down voting is not appropriate.

Comment: "_but date at one place at that moment is not the same at the same moment at different place..._"  Actually that's not correct.  A Java `Date` object simply stores the number of milliseconds since the epoch.  That value does not change regardless of what TimeZone you're in.  If I do something "_right now_" in the United States and in India, both events are occuring at the same moment in time relative to Jan 1, 1970 UTC (which is how a timestampe is defined).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but at this time, I am looking at it in a different way. Your way can be implemented as well but the way I am looking at it will add more complexity to the solution I am trying to implement. I have tasks, and their status needs to change to "overDue" ones the Time in that particular's timezone crosses midnight. I think it just the way we are looking at the solution that is making the difference here. I say this is a good discussion we have. Its made me more confident about both the solutions, and the way we look at them.

Comment: I guess you're trying to _completely_ change the date to a different moment in time rather than trying to display the same moment in time with two different strings.... I hope that's what you want.

Comment: Local TIme zone is:America/Los_Angeles, the other one is UTC
the following is the output to toString()
Local: Thu Jun 27 08:45:32 EST 2013
UTC: Thu Jun 27 15:45:32 EST 2013

Comment: Its same time in different timezones: one time zone is America/Los_Angeles and another one is UTC.

Comment: Have a look at the output I have added to question now.

Comment: I am running it  from Sydney, Australia so new Date() timezone is different for me, it you look there is a variation in the time when its 3:51 PM your time its 10:51 PM at UTC. My code also handles the daylight saving. Today at midnight the code gives the UTC time as 14:00:00 and if I set Date to some day in December I get the UTC time as 13:00:00, So it caters for Daylight saving.

Comment: Mate, I got your point, I also understand that there are no TimeZones associated with the Date Object. The point is to share and discuss the knowledge.